# How to get the identified area from tensor flow?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

I have created a simple model in TF to identify cars.
it identified the bellow image as a car:

[image]

What I would like to have is the area(or crop of the area) of the actual identified car as follows:
[image]

any ideas if it is possible with Tensorflow? my current python code is looking like that:

```
file_name = 'mustangTest.png'
input_height = 299
input_width = 299
input_mean = 0
input_std = 255
input_layer = "Mul"
output_layer = "final_result"
t = read_tensor_from_image_file(src,input_height=input_height,input_width=input_width,input_mean=input_mean,input_std=input_std)
        input_name = "import/" + input_layer
        output_name = "import/" + output_layer
        input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
        output_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(output_name);

        with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
            results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0],{input_operation.outputs[0]: t})
            results = np.squeeze(results)
        top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
        print("car is " + top_k[0]")
```

Comment: What architecture does your network have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initial note:** Since you talk about having "created a simple model" and having said model "identify this image as car", I'll assume you're not actually using a model for object detection, but one that does simple classification.

The problem you're trying to solve is a different problem than the one you trained your network to solve.

You have a network that was trained to tell you **whether an image you feed to it contains a car**. This is a classification problem.

What you want now is **the area where the car actually is in the image**. This is a much harder problem to solve, because now your network doesn't need to output anymore "I see a car" vs. "I don't see a car", but instead, in the **simplest** formulation, "I see a car in the rectangle (x,y,w,h)". In another formulation, more similar to what your desired output would be, you would have **per *each pixel* a classification like "it's a car" or "not a car"**. These problems are then object *detection* and *segmentation*.

There are studies out there that tackle these problems ([one example](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.08083) and [another](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf)), but my suggestion is to have a look at Tensorflow's [object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) which have pretrained models you might exploit for your use-case.

Comment: If i have a pretrained model(based on google inception), can i use this api? or should i retrain it?

Comment: I don't know this for sure, because I don't know the architectures used in that API, but I'd guess you can't use a pretrained classification model as part of the detection pipeline. **I may be wrong** though, I don't know detection algorithms in depth. My suggestion is to head to the [model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md), pick one of those and try out the [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb)